# Need to know why the code behaves in this way - explanation code in C

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    c = f(3, 5);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);    
    c = f(4, 2);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);    
    c = f(2, 4);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);    
    c = f(3, 3);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);
}

int f(int d, int e) {
    if (e > 0)
        return f(d, e - 1) + f(d, e - 1);
    else
        return d;    
}
```

I know the code gives me the product between `d` (the first number in `f`) and `2` elevated to the second number in f(function)

The problem is that I don't understand why it gives me such output, I don't see any operators within the code (something like an equation d*2^e).
An a deep explanation would be very appreciated, feel free to recommend any material which can be helpful in learning C.

Comment: [**Recursion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) appears to be on the reading list.

Comment: Where can I find such recursion?

Comment: google, bing, yahoo, duckduckgo,....

Comment: Wait ,is the recursion what gives me that output?

Comment: Why not just work through the calculations with pencil and paper -- i.e. pretend that you are the computer. It shouldn't take more than a few minutes. Understanding will come.

Comment: @LucaMuscolo In order to understand recursion, one must first... understand recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple recursive function, I can write in such way:

```
         |  f(d, e-1) + f(d, e-1)   if e > 0
f(d,e) = |
         |  d                       otherwise
```

But I can simply add two equal terms `f(d,e-1)`, and then it becomes:

```
         |  2* f(d, e-1)    if e > 0
f(d,e) = |
         |  d               otherwise
```

In order to let you understand, just try to expand the function. Following the rule, I can write:

```
f(d,0) = d    for all d  // Identify function
```

That because the definition, since `e=0`.

Going ahead:

```
f(d, 1) = 2*f(d, 0) =           2*d

f(d, 2) = 2*f(d, 1) = 2*(2*d) = 4*d

f(d, 3) = 2*f(d, 2) = 2*(4*d) = 8*d

...  // Inductivly...
f(d, k) =  2^k *d     // for k > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `f(d, n)` computes **d * 2<sup>n</sup>**.  Here is a proof by induction:

1. `f(d, 0)` returns `d`, which is equal to **d * 2<sup>0</sup>**
2. `f(d, n + 1)` returns `f(d, n + 1 - 1) + f(d, n + 1 - 1)`, which simplifies into `2 * f(d, n)`.  If `f(d, n)` computes **d * 2<sup>n</sup>**, then `f(d, n + 1)` computes **2 * d * 2<sup>n</sup>**, which is exactly **d * 2<sup>n+1</sup>**.

QED: We can conclude by induction that `f(d, n)` computes **d * 2<sup>n</sup>** for all `n >= 0`.

Comment: Thank for replying , but how do I know from just reading the code that it makes the product of d with 2^e?

Comment: You read through the code and understand it. Go through the code and take the execution route and then come out with the result.

Comment: @LucaMuscolo:  I quoted the code literally in steps 1 and 2.  step 2 corresponds to the `if (e > 0)` branch, step 1 to the `else` branch.